# Usage of where in if let assignment in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, where-clause, option-type, swift3

The Swift documentation at page 61 of the Swift manual hints to the possibility of using `where` to join an optional binding with a regular condition. Yet when I do it I have a warning suggesting me to substitute the `where` with a comma like in the following piece of code:

```
if let geocodingError = error as? NSError where geocodingError.code == 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example with two conditions

```
if let x = y, let a = b, a == x && !x.isEmpty {
```

Answer (score 139):

In Swift 3 this syntax has changed.

What was

`if let x = y, a = b where a == x {`

Is now

`if let x = y, let a = b, a == x {`

The justification is that each sub-clause of the `if ... {` is now an independent boolean test.

See the Xcode [Release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_4/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_4.pdf) & the [Swift Evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md) for more info about this change.

Comment: Yet another change. Everywhere in the documentation the where clause is still present. Anyway using the form you suggested works fine.

Comment: Is this change described anywhere else than in the (not fully public) Xcode 8 Beta 4 release notes? E.g. evolution/other official docs? I might note to other readers that we're still prompted to use the `where` clause to separate the variable binding from the conditional if using e.g. Swift 3.0-dev in the IBM Sandbox.

Comment: The documentation updated to Swift 3 still has where as well the online one. To say this is confusing is an understatement. It now seems they are changing things just for the sake of it, like for the DispatchQueue that now needs deadline instead of when.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci Swift 3.0 is still in beta so this is expected. I do believe, however, that all somewhat noteworthy changes should be included in [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution), but I haven't seen this one covered there (maybe I've simply missed it).

Comment: In fact the just updated Swift documentation now has the comma at page 61 instead of where.

Comment: @dfri It was a part of [SE-0099 "Restructuring Condition Clauses"](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md)

Comment: @Grimxn Well, it's your answer ;) I generally don't like to edit other people's answers without their permission, unless it's grammar related – although I have edited the link in at your request.

Comment: This syntax is so bloody inconsistent it makes me want to scream. It's like we have different people with wildly different philosophies developing different parts of the language and are left with this mess that is Swift 3. RIP consistent syntax. :(

Answer (score 4):

In xcode 9

```
if let str = textField.text as String!, !str.isEmpty
{
   params[key] = str
   TextFieldHelper.setup(textField: textField)
}
else
{ 
   TextFieldHelper.error(textField: textField)
}
```

Comment: To clarify: it is the version of the Swift language—not the version of Xcode—which determines the available syntax.