# Swift3: if let where statements

Tags: if-statement, swift3

I have an `if let` statement with a `where` clause in Swift2 but the syntax is not correct for Swift3.

```
if let car = createCar(), let color = car.color where color == UIColor.redColor() { }
```

How do you convert this code to Swift3?

Comment: What are you asking? How is what in Swift 3? You have two lines of unrelated code in your question and nothing else. What is your question?

Comment: @Fogmeister The `where` clause –  which is not available in Swift 3 –  is the relation.

Comment: @vadian ah ok. Well there's no reason to not put that in the question. A question should not require the reader to interpret what is being asked.

Comment: @Fogmeister Actually it's in the question: *if let **where** statements ... convert ... to swift3* ;-)

Comment: @vadian see edit. How it makes everything much clearer :) It makes it so much easier when you take 30 seconds to write an actual question rather than "Need converting to Swift 3". I realise it's not your question :) But the OP has gone quiet :)

Comment: Thank you for your help) I agree that short questions aren't understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of where in if let assignment in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762513/usage-of-where-in-if-let-assignment-in-swift)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is actually in the statement, neither swift2 nor swift3 will accept it, the right for swift3 is:

```
if let car = createCar(), car.color == UIColor.red { }
```